# How to "find" a collection and compare value with its inner object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Hmmm I don't know how to clearly state the title.  hopefully the following explanation will be better.

I have a schema like that:

```
company = new Schema {
  name: String,
  contact: {}
}
```

For example:

```
{
  name:'cnn'
  contact: {
      address:'whatever',
      phone1: '1-800-123-1234',
      url: 'cnn.com'
   }
}
```

When I do a find (or findOne), I can do this..

```
db.company.findOne({name:'cnn'});
```

What if I want to search for the value in the 'contact'?

e.g. search for record with url='cnn.com'

or to find out which records has the key "url" in 'contact'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a sub-key, you just give the path to the key delimited by periods.

```
db.company.findOne({"contact.url": "cnn.com"})
```

To find out which records have a contact URL:

```
db.company.findOne({"contact.url": {$ne: null}})
```

Note that these queries will be full collection scans unless you create an index for the subkey queried. Use judiciously.

Comment: Aaah.. No wonder.  I use contact.url  but without the quote. and i have tried contact:{url:'cnn.com'}  .. ah.. no wonder.. thanks . :)